# The limit of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help with this exercise!

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1^4+2^4+...+n^4}{n^5}.$

I saw somewhere online that $1^4+2^4+...+n^4=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}$.

But I dont understand why!

So following that then,

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1^4+2^4+...+n^4}{n^5}=$
$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30n^5}=$
$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30n^4}=\dfrac15.$

And after that what!? Do I multiply and then use L'Hopital?

Comment: Do you mean $1^4+2^4+3^4+\dots+n^4$?  You have a rogue $n$ appearing too early in what you have written.

Comment: Why can be a little tough to understand and come to, but in the meantime you coul try to prove that formula you saw somewhere online by induction, say.

Comment: Should be $1^4+2^4+\cdots+n^4$ in the numerator and not $1+2n^4+\cdots$. Correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Fun fact: You dont ***need*** Faulhaber's, this can also be done using integration!

Comment: I don't understand the question(s) at the very end. Just above that line you've given the answer, $1/5$. What else is there to do?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi how would you do that? Do you mean using discrete antiderivatives, ie finite calculus?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent See [J.G.'s statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3954019/811225). The sum is asymptotic to that integral. So, the discreetness *disappears* as n gets bigger.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens when you rush into learning calculus!

The quantity $S(n) = 1^4 + 2^4 + \cdots + n^4$ can be summed in a variety of ways. One such way is to guess that it grows like a fifth degree polynomial, then use Lagrange interpolation and induction. Another way might be to notice that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (i+1)^5 - i^5 = n^5$$
is easy to evaluate. But alternatively,
$$(i+1)^5 - i^5 = 5i^4 + 10i^3 + 10i^2 + 5i + 1.$$
I leave it as an exercise to you on how to derive from here; now to your question on l'Hopital's.

You have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30n^5}.$$

The numerator is a fifth degree polynomial. The denominator is a fifth degree polynomial. So the limit will just be the ratio of the leading coefficients, $6/30 = 1/5.$ Why? Well, imagine we have a simpler case,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^2 + 3n + 1}{n^2}.$$
Then
$$\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2} = 1 + \frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
As $n$ goes to infinity, anything with an $n$ in the denominator will go to 0, and you're just left with 1. If you expanded out that fifth degree numerator, you'd quickly find the same trick applies and all but the leading term dies.

Comment: Nice trick with regards to L' Hopital, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\sum_{k=1}^nk^4$ must be divisible by $n(n+1)$, so that the obvious extension to negative $n$ achieves $0-0^4=0$ at $n=-1$. The large-$n$ behaviour is asymptotic to $\int_0^nx^4dx=\tfrac15n^5$. We can determine coefficients in $\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=\tfrac15n(n+1)(n^3+An^2+Bn+C)$ from the sum at three values of $n$, say $n\in\{1,\,2,\,3\}$, thereby acquiring simultaneous equations. This gives $A=\tfrac32,\,B=\tfrac16,\,C=-\tfrac16$, after which the rational root theorem finds the factor $n+\tfrac12$.